# lump factor based on another column

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

The example shows measurements of production output of different factories,
where the first columns denotes the factory
and the last column the amount produced.

```
factory <- c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","D")
production <- c(15, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2,20,5)
df <- data.frame(factory, production)
df
  factory production
1       A         15
2       A          2
3       B          1
4       B          1
5       B          2
6       B          1
7       B          2
8       C         20
9       D          5
```

Now I want to lump together the factories into fewer levels, based on their total output in this data set.

With the normal forcats::fct_lump, I can lump them by the number of rows in which thy appear, e.g. for making 3 levels:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>% mutate(factory=fct_lump(factory,2))
      factory production
    1       A         15
    2       A          2
    3       B          1
    4       B          1
    5       B          2
    6       B          1
    7       B          2
    8   Other         20
    9   Other          5
```

but I want to lump them based on the sum(production), retaining the top n=2 factories (by total output) and lump the remaining factories. Desired result:

```
1       A         15
2       A          2
3   Other          1
4   Other          1
5   Other          2
6   Other          1
7   Other          2
8       C         20
9   Other          5
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to apply a specific philosophy in order to group factories together based on their sum of production. Note that this philosophy has to do with the actual values you have in your (real) dataset.

**Option 1**

Here's an example that groups together factories that have a sum production equal to 15 or less. If you want another grouping you can modify the threshold (e.g. use 18 instead of 15)

```
factory <- c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","D")
production <- c(15, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2,20,5)
df <- data.frame(factory, production, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(factory) %>%
  mutate(factory_new = ifelse(sum(production) > 15, factory, "Other")) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   factory production factory_new
#   <chr>        <dbl> <chr>      
# 1 A               15 A          
# 2 A                2 A          
# 3 B                1 Other      
# 4 B                1 Other      
# 5 B                2 Other      
# 6 B                1 Other      
# 7 B                2 Other      
# 8 C               20 C          
# 9 D                5 Other
```

I'm creating `factory_new` without removing the (original) `factory` column.

**Option 2**

Here's an example where you can rank / order the factories based on their production and then you can pick a number of top factories to keep as they are and group the rest

```
factory <- c("A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","D")
production <- c(15, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2,20,5)
df <- data.frame(factory, production, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

# get ranked factories based on sum production
df %>%
  group_by(factory) %>%
  summarise(SumProd = sum(production)) %>%
  arrange(desc(SumProd)) %>%
  pull(factory) -> vec_top_factories

# input how many top factories you want to keep
# rest will be grouped together
n = 2

# apply the grouping based on n provided
df %>%
  group_by(factory) %>%
  mutate(factory_new = ifelse(factory %in% vec_top_factories[1:n], factory, "Other")) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   factory production factory_new
#   <chr>        <dbl> <chr>      
# 1 A               15 A          
# 2 A                2 A          
# 3 B                1 Other      
# 4 B                1 Other      
# 5 B                2 Other      
# 6 B                1 Other      
# 7 B                2 Other      
# 8 C               20 C          
# 9 D                5 Other
```

Comment: That is a good step, but still it does not keep the top n separated and lumping the rest.

Comment: But this is the ideal output you described.

Comment: For the example, yes. But forcats::fct_lump takes the argument n and keeps the top n levels (by abundance) and lumps the rest into one. Maybe I need to clarify that.

Comment: In the solution above the philosophy is to change the `sum(production)` threshold in order to get different groups. So, you can use `18` instead of `15` and you'll get a different grouping. If you want to provide `n` instead I can modify the code...

Answer (score 5):

Just specify the weight argument `w`:

```
> df %>% 
+   mutate(factory = fct_lump_n(factory, 2, w = production))
  factory production
1       A         15
2       A          2
3   Other          1
4   Other          1
5   Other          2
6   Other          1
7   Other          2
8       C         20
9   Other          5
```

Note: use `forcats::fct_lump_n` because the generic `fct_lump` is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `base R` as well by creating a logical condition with `ave`

```
df$factory_new <- "Other"
i1 <- with(df, ave(production, factory, FUN = sum) > 15)
df$factory_new[i1] <- df$factory[i1]
```